# Positivity of $L(1,\chi)$ for real Dirichlet's character

Tags: nt.number-theory, characters, quadratic-residues

Let $\chi$ be a real nonprincipal Dirichlet's character modulo $m$.

In [my
answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25794/shortest-most-elegant-proof-for-l1-chi-neq-0/25822#25822) to the question on $L(1,\chi)$, I explain a trick for showing that $L(1,\chi)>0$ on the simplest examples
of the real characters modulo 3 and 4. The proof goes as follows: one takes
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi(n)x^n=\frac1{1-x^m}\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\chi(j)x^j
$$
and uses Abel's theorem to write
$$
L(1,\chi)=\int_0^1f(x)dx;
$$
since the corresponding function $f(x)$ is positive on $(0,1)$, the latter integral has to be positive.

Clearly, $1-x^m>0$ on $(0,1)$, so that the required positivity of $f(x)$ reduces to the positivity of
the polynomial
$$
g_\chi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\chi(n)x^n
$$
on $(0,1)$. Trying to verify on how generalizable is this method for $m>3$, I was quite surprised to see that it works
perfectly further; for example,
$$
g(x)=x(1-x)(1-x^2)>0 \quad\text{if } m=5
$$
or
$$
g(x)=x(1-x)(1+x^2+2x^3+3x^4+2x^5+x^6+x^8)>0 \quad\text{if } m=11.
$$
Honestly saying, the positivity is not so obvious in many other examples (for example, $m=19$) but nevertheless it is
always holds for small values $m\le30$.

**Question.** Given an integer $m>2$ and a real nonprincipal character $\chi$ modulo $m$,
is it true that $g_\chi(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$? If not, are there (in)finitely many $m$ for
which the positivity does not take place? Is the above strategy for showing $L(1,\chi)\ne0$ discussed
in the literature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called Fekete polynomials, and you can find out a great deal about them [here](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/fekete.pdf). Unfortunately they tend to have lots of real zeros in $(0,1)$ when $m$ is large.

Comment: Thanks, David! Never heard of them... Feteke or Fekete? And is $L(1,\chi)>0$ for some $m$?

Comment: fekete, sorry!  I'm not sure I understand your second question.

Comment: The story about Fekete polynomials is really intriguing. Even the only $\chi$ in this case is the Legendre (Jacobi) symbol, it seems that similar results should be true for real $\chi$ in general. As for my extra question, the fact that $g(x)$ alternates on $(0,1)$ many times does not imply that the "average" $L(1,\chi)$ of $g(x)/(1-x^m)$ could be done negative. So, are there examples with $L(1,\chi)<0$?

Comment: Oh, no, the inequality $L(1,\chi)>0$ for $\chi$ real goes back to Dirichlet, and is an immediate consequence of his famous class number formula.

Comment: I should have had in mind this implication. Very nice to start a day with nice knowledge. Thank you for this lesson, David! 

Comment: Wadim and David: there's an easier reason why L(1,chi) can't be negative for real nontrivial chi: the function L(s,chi) for s > 0 is obviously real-valued. As s --> infty it tends to 1, which is positive, and we know L(s,chi) is nonzero for s > 1 by the Euler product.  Therefore by continuity L(s,chi) > 0 for s > 1, hence by taking a limit from the right L(1,chi) is definitely not negative. It's not 0 either (harder!), so L(1,chi) > 0.

Comment: It is not the same, but Chowla then Rosser chased around vaguely similar ideas (weighted sums) to show that $L(s,\chi)>0$ for real $s>0$ for various real $\chi$.
Chowla: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa1/aa119.pdf
Rosser: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-10/S0002-9904-1949-09306-0/S0002-9904-1949-09306-0.pdf


Comment: Junkie, thank you very much for the links to Chowla's method, which is not surprising to me from the analytic point of view, but I did not expect it working in this $L$-function context. It reminds me about Pr\'evost's proof of Ap\'ery's theorem (irrationality of $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$). I am too thankful today, but I am very happy to see so many useful comments on the question.

Answer (score 5):

As David pointed out, it is known that for large m these polynomials have many zeroes. This is very unfortunate for the following reason: If you assume $g_{\chi}$ is non-negative then it follows by Mellin inversion that the L-function $L(s,\chi)$ can not have a Siegel zero (or, more generally, any zero on the positive real axis).

Comment: Thanks, Marc! The heuristics is already indicated in David's reference, but only for the Legendre symbol. I acknowledge your contribution by upvoting.