# Is there another proof for Dirichlet's theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-progression, prime-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a “non-analytic” proof of Dirichlet’s theorem on primes known or possible?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16735/is-a-non-analytic-proof-of-dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-known-or-possible)

Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression states that there are infinitely many primes of the form $kn+h$ given that $k$ and $h$ are coprime. Is there a short proof for this?

Comment: short answer: no.

Comment: "It is rash to assert that a particular theorem cannot proved in a particular way." Thought you were an endorser of that viewpoint, Professor K. C.

Comment: I asked a more focused version of this question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16735/is-a-non-analytic-proof-of-dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-known-or-possible

Comment: Every proof I've even seen takes the same form up until the final steps. (1) Introduce the character group of the unit group of $Z/N$. (2) Consider the sum $\sum \chi(k)/k$, where $chi$ is a character of $Z/N$. Notice that this sum is much larger for $\chi$ trivial than for $\chi$ nontrivial. (3) Use the multiplicativity of $\chi$, and step 2, to deduce that $\sum 1/p$ grows much faster than $\sum \chi(p)/p$. (4) THE HARD STEP: Deduce somehow that $\sum \chi(k)/k \neq 0$, so $- \sum \chi(p)/p$ is also small. (5) Deduce the theorem.

Comment: Even if you take the hard step (4) for granted, I don't think that any careful exposition of (1)-(3) and (5) can be truly called short.

Comment: J.H.S.: I didn't mean there *can't* be a short proof, but rather that (right now) there isn't one.  That's what it seemed he was asking about, not some meta-mathematical query on the possible existence of a short proof.

Comment: It was hard to guess that from the way in which the comment is stated, Professor Conrad. 

Comment: Queston: Can a 5-6 pages proof including all the details and on a level accessible to undergraduate students with a basic course in complex analysis (including convergence of Dirichlet-series) be considered short? How about 4 pages proof if these undergraduate students have a basic background in commutative algebra, so there is no need to define Dirichlet-Characters and prove orthogonality?

Comment: ex-falso:  you don't need commutative algebra to understand Dirichlet characters. Do any books on comm. alg. talk about characters on finite abelian groups?  (Sure, you can talk about the dual space of a finitely generated torsion module over a PID, which for PID = Z is the  characters on a finite abelian group, but that seems like overkill, and moreover any intuition one could have for the abstract idea I just mentioned would come from already knowing the theory of characters on finite abelian groups.  At least that is how I see it.) 

Comment: ex-falso 2:  The convergence of Dirichlet series is not part of a basic course in complex analysis.  Those series are not a general part of the analyst's toolbox. So you'd need some pages in the proof which discuss what they are. You could give a very short proof of Dirichlet's theorem to a sufficiently sophisticated mathematician, but I don't think it would be in the spirit of the short proof as requested.  (In Witt's collected works there is a one-page proof of the prime number theorem.)

Comment: A clarification about my description of characters generalizing to a dual space: I meant, for a finitely generated torsion module over PID R, that its "dual space" would be the R-linear maps on the module with values in K/R, where K is the fraction field (of course not valued in R, as there wouldn't be anything).  For R = Z this means values in Q/Z, which is the torsion points on the circle and thus a place that characters on finite abelian groups can take their values. 

Comment: I have voted to close, but not for the reason that others have (they said "exact duplicate").  Rather, I think that the question "does there exist a short proof of Theorem X?" is inherently vague and subjective and could well lead to arguments of the form "Proof X which assumes Y and takes Z pages is / is not short."  Please clarify what you actually want to know.  There are proofs of Dirichlet's theorem which avoid complex or even real analysis, but I am not aware of a proof which could be given in an undergraduate course in less than a week of lectures.

Comment: Just to  clarify: When I was taking my basic course in complex analysis as an undergraduate, Dirichlet series including abscisse of convergence and absolute convergence were part of it. Same with the algebra: Two semesters Linear Algebra, then two semesters algebra, where the second semester of algebra was basically introduction to commutative algebra (and some other stuff), and Dirichlet characters were dealt with within this course, well actually in the part about finite abelian groups. Commutative rings came later. BTW, both com. algebra and complex analysis were in the fourth semester. 

Comment: That was/is standard here. I was expecting that this might not be the case everywhere, hence my 2 questions. Thanks for the clarifications! 

Comment: Exact duplicate? No way! How do you know that a non-analytic proof of the theorem is to be shorter than the current approach? 

Comment: Why has someone brought this back from the depths? Is cataloguing **really** that important?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are short proofs of particular instances of the result. For example, emulating the Euclidean assault on the infinitude of primes, one can establish, almost effortlessly, that there are infinitely many primes of the form 4k+3. Nevertheless, you have to be warned that there is no way to strenghten this technique in order to get the result for every arithmetic progression. You may want to take a look at [**1**]. In that note, Professor Murty mentions that it was I. Schur the one who first derived a sufficient condition for the existence of an "Euclidean" proof for the infinitude of primes in the arithmetic progression {$mk+a$}$_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$.

**Edit**: As David Speyer mentioned above one on the main ingredients in the proof is a certain non-vanishing result for L-series. Hence, a way in which one might shorten the proof is by spotting the shortest demonstration for the corresponding non-vanishing theorem. I higly recommend that you take a look at the thread in [**2**] if you wish to learn more about this particular matter.

**References**

[**1**] M. R. Murty, *Primes in certain arithmetic progressions*, J. Madras. Univ. (1988), 161-169.

[**2**] Shortest/Most elegant proof for the non-vanishing of $L(1, \chi)$ :

[Shortest/Most elegant proof for $L(1,\chi)\neq 0$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25794/shortest-most-elegant-proof-for-l1-chi-neq-0/25815#25815)

Comment: Oh, that's a different matter!  The person who asked the question should definitely clarify if he was asking for a short proof of the general theorem or if he'd be content with a short proof of some special cases (which *usually* don't give a flavor of the general proof). 

Comment: Point taken, Sire. Nonetheless, I decided to enter the reply because I thought it'd help to disseminate the fact that there are specific arithmetic progressions for which the related proofs are as short as possible.

Comment: More information here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dirichleteuclid.pdf

Comment: There's also a short proof for $4k+1$. Assume there were a finite number of such primes, take their product, square it, and add one. Then there is a prime $p$ that divides this result. This forces $-1$ to be a square in $F_p$, hence $p$ is congruent to 1 modulo 4, contradiction.

Comment: For more on Murty's result that the usual elementary approach is doomed to failure look at:
http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Epppollac/euc4.pdf

There Paul Pollack shows that a commonly believed conjecture implies a generalization of Murty's result to a broader type of elementary proof.

Comment: I am surprised no one has mentioned http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PNTforaps.pdf in this thread.