# Distribution of quadratic residues of a fixed number without using Dedekind zeta function

Tags: quadratic-residues, analytic-number-theory

Let $n > 1$ be a square-free natural number, which is fixed. The assertion to be proved is the following:

> Let $p$ run through primes. Then, $$\left( \frac{n}{p} \right)$$ is equally distributed between $1$ and $-1$.

The precise statement of which is to be made using the appropriate asymptotic expressions.

J-P. Serre, "A Course in Arithmetic", outlines a proof of the above assertion just after the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions. That proof uses the zeta function of number fields. I am not able to shake off the feeling that it should be provable without using this. That is, it should be possible to prove this statement just using the properties of Dirichlet $L$-functions, and elementary arguments on quadratic residues. However I am not able to construct such a proof either, since I am not very skilled in this type of matters. So I ask here, is such a proof known?

Comment: This is fairly straightforward to prove if one knows that
$L(1,\chi)\ne0$ where $\chi$ is the Dirichlet character
extending $p\mapsto (n/p)$. See
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25794/shortest-most-elegant-proof-for-l1-chi-neq-0/25797#25797 for my thoughts on this.

Comment: @Robin Chapman: I had indeed read your "real variable" proof of Dirichlet's theorem, if that is what you mean. But that article does not contain a proof of this assertion. I also feel that the proof should not be difficult; but I am not able to make the connection myself.

Comment: If $n$ is prime this follows easily from the quantitative form of Dirichlet's theorem and quadratic reciprocity.  It might follow for general $n$ by multiplicativity, but this is not obvious, because we can't immediately rule out correlations between the primes with respect to which the factors of $n$ are residues.  I suspect we can find theorems to deal with this, though.

Comment: For Dirichlet density one needs little more than the nonvanishing
of the L-function at $1$. For natural density if one also
has the non-vanishing of the $L$-function on the rest of
the line $s=1+it$ (which is easier than the non-vanishing at $s=1$)
then one can use standard results, for instance the Wiener-Ikehara
Tauberian theorem to complete the proof. (Compare for
instance Zagier's excellent *Monthly* paper on PNT).

Comment: @Robin Chapman: I do not mean that your article does not contain a proof that $L(1, \chi) \neq 0$. I meant the implication that this statement implies the assertion I made in the statement of the question. My question is not really analytic, though I tagged it analytic-number-theory. All I need is the proof that the theorems on Dirciclet L-functions  implies the equal distribution of quadratic residues. I expect that it would be rather elementary.

Comment: So is the nonvanishing of $L(1, \chi)$ not one of the standard results on Dirichlet $L$-functions for you?

Comment: @David Speyer: It is one of the standard results. But from that how would it follow? 

Comment: If you accept `$\lim_{s \to 1^{+}} \left| \sum \left( \frac{n}{p} \right) p^{-s} \right| < \infty$` as the way that you make your density statement precise, then this follows easily from $L(1, \chi) \neq 0$, as `$\log L(s, \chi) = \sum \chi(p)/p^s + O(1)$`. If you want to use some other measure of density, then you need the usual Tauberian arguments.

Comment: @David Speyer: What is $\chi$ here? For the statement you cite, it should be a character modulo $n$ and it escapes me which character you mean. 

Comment: The character $\left( \frac{n}{} \right)$, which is a character modulo $4n$ by quadratic reciprocity. 

Comment: Ah! I see, thanks. If you could write it down as an answer, I could accept it and forget about this question. Otherwise, if you think this question is too trivial to merit an answer, and if you don't have objections, I can delete this answer.

Comment: I might add one slight omission: Now we know that the quadratic residues of $4n$ are equally distributed between $1$ and $-1$. There remains a small checking that it indeed implies the same for $n$.

Comment: In two comments above: I meant, I can delete this question. 

Comment: If David does not post an answer within a few hours, you can also just collect together the best observations and put those as your answer. If it would bother you about some votes going to you instead of David you can make your answer, or the whole question, community wiki. I do not know how to do that myself but it cannot be too difficult. That way people who might be interested but did not follow the first few hours of comments can see an organized answer in one place.

Comment: @Will Jagy: Will do so. Maybe I will wait for a day or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer summarizes the above discussion: Extend $p \mapsto \left( \frac{n}{p} \right)$ to a multiplicative function $\chi$ on the positive integers. By quadratic reciprocity, $\chi$ is periodic modulo $4n$, and it is multiplicative by construction, so it is a character. We know that $L(1, \chi) \neq 0$. Thus, $\lim_{s \to 1^{+}} |\log L(s,\chi)| < \infty$.

We compute:
$$\log L(s, \chi) = - \sum \log \left( 1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s} \right) = \sum \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s} + O(1).$$

So $\sum \left( \frac{n}{p} \right)/p^s$ is bounded as $s \to 1^{+}$. A little more work shows that the limit as $s \to 1^{+}$ exists.

If you want to prove results like that $\sum \left( \frac{n}{p} \right)/p$ converges, or that $|\sum_{p < N} \left( \frac{n}{p} \right)| = o(N)$, then you need Tauberian methods, as discussed in any book on analytic number theory.